# In angular api $watch returns a de-registration function for this listener what is the meaning of de-registration

Tags: javascript, angularjs

`$watchCollection(obj, listener);`  this method return a de-registration function  what is de-registration function ,when will it be destory or it will always be here for the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A deregistration means that you can call the function when you want it to stop watching the collection. So if you're watching for some change, and you find after the change is made you no longer need to watch the collection, you can call the deregistration function to stop the watch happening and destroy the watch.